# good practice mvc with spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

with spring, when we have a service layer, dao layer and controller to manage a form data (list, selected list value, data found by the bd)

is it a good practice to put all this data in a object?

is a good practice to create a method in the service layer who will call many dao method to feed listbox... and feed a ford object or it's better

to call different method in the service layer from the controller ?

```
public class UserForm {

    private SearchCritera searchCritera;
    private List<String> city;
    private List<String> country;
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class SearchCritera {

    private List<String> selectedCity;
    private List<String> selectedCountry;
    ...
}
```

maybe there are a better way that the two idea I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it makes more sense to have what you suggested:

- a DAO layer where you access the database with single operations
- a service layer where you aggregate calls to the DAO layer and do some business logic
- a web / controller layer where you make calls to the service layer and do what is necessary for the view to be rendered.

Keep in mind that either way you're designing your application, you have to configure it so that the transactions are dealt with properly. If your service layer is transactionnal and there are multiple calls from the web layer within the same method to the service layer, then if something goes wrong, likely the database might not end up in a clean state.
What you want to avoid too is to have business logic in your controller layer.